# Using sys.exit in for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, exit

I am writing a small python script that iterates through a large json output and grabs the information I need and puts it into small dictionaries. It then iterates through the dictionaries to look for an key called `restartcount`. If the count is more than more than 3 but less than 5 it prints `warning`. If greater than 5 it prints `critical`. However this script is set to be a nagios plugin which requires exit codes to be placed with warning `sys.exit(1)`, and `sys.exit(2)` for critical. If you look at my script I use my function to grab the info I need into a small dictionary, then run a for loop. If I place a `sys.exit` after inside any if statement I iterate only through the first dictionary and the rest are not checked. Any help will be appreciated as to how to incorporate the exit codes without losing skipping or missing any information.

Code:

```
import urllib2
import json
import argparse
from sys import exit

def get_content(pod):
    kube = {}
    kube['name'] = pod["metadata"]["name"]
    kube['phase'] = pod["status"]["phase"]
    kube['restartcount'] = pod["status"]["containerStatuses"][0]["restartCount"]
    return kube

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description='Monitor Kubernetes Pods' )
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--warning', type=int, help='levels we should look into',default=3)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--critical', type=int, help='its gonna explode',default=5)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, help='port to access api server',default=8080)
    args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    api_call = "http://localhost:{}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/".format(args.port)
    req = urllib2.urlopen(api_call).read()
    content = json.loads(req)
except urllib2.URLError:
    print 'URL Error. Please re-check the API call'
    exit(2)


for pods in content.get("items"):
    try:
        block = get_content(pods)
        print block
    except KeyError:
        print 'Container Failed'
        exit(2)

    if block["restartcount"] >= args.warning and block["restartcount"] < args.critical:
        print "WARNING | {} restart count  is {}".format(block["name"], block["restartcount"])

    if block["restartcount"] >= args.critical:
        print "CRITICAL | {} restart count  is {}".format(block["name"], block["restartcount"])
```

what the `block` variable looks like:

```
{'phase': u'Running', 'restartcount': 0, 'name': u'pixels-1.0.9-k1v5u'}
```

Comment: sys.ext exits the application. if you are trying to leave a loop use `break` if you are trying to continue looping use `continue`... if you want to exit after finishing the loop, set a flag inside the loop, use `continue` and check the flag outside of the loop

Comment: @Busturdust - I know that very well. However I have to use sys.exit in order to report the status of the process to nagios

Comment: exit only after the loop, setting some flag condition inside and checking it after, exiting if true?

Comment: Tried that. It fails to print the status and only gives a warning ( or critical)

Comment: seperate flags? check both?

Comment: Exiting out it not a problem, exiting out IMMEDIATELY after the print is what I am trying

Comment: If you exit immediately, how do you expect further execution of the loop?

Comment: Thats why I posted the question, asking for pointers on how to change my strategy.

Comment: Would love to know how this question is "off topic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a variable called something like `exit_status`. Initialize it to 0, and set it as needed in your code (e.g. where you are currently calling `exit`). At the end of program execution, call `sys.exit(exit_status)` (and no where else).

Rewriting the last section of your code:

```
exit_status = 0
for pods in content.get("items"):
    try:
        block = get_content(pods)
        print block
    except KeyError:
        print 'Container Failed'
        exit(2)

    if block["restartcount"] >= args.warning and block["restartcount"] < args.critical:
        print "WARNING | {} restart count  is {}".format(block["name"], block["restartcount"])
        if exit_status < 1: exit_status = 1

    if block["restartcount"] >= args.critical:
        print "CRITICAL | {} restart count  is {}".format(block["name"], block["restartcount"])
        exit_status = 2

sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Comment: As stated above, Ive already tried this step, it gives me a warning flag but the print statement is "lost"

Comment: Is the code above the current code you are using? Can you show an example of the "lost" print statement?

Comment: yeah. Removed the sys.exit in the for loops (as you have suggested) as thats not what I am aiming for

Comment: I updated my answer - I hope it works for you, or at least clarifies the approach I am suggesting.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the only way. I tried adding the statements to lists or dictionaries but it all comes down to the main issue, throwing in an exit statement in the middle of a loop which ends in prematurely ( and right so )

Answer (score 0):

The variable approach is correct
Problem is that as you check further you probably set it to 1 when it was already 2 so I would suggest add here a condition not to set it to 1 if it is already 2